# Data Parsing Question C#

Tags: c#

I am getting back data in a string like the following:

```
dog,cat,snake,bird,cow,parrot,lion
grass,green,fruit,bag,car,melon,coat
apple,orange,grape,butter,jelly,chips,milk
```

I want to put this data in a gridView where each of these rows stands for a row in a gridView, I also wanna take the first entry or each row and populate a dropdown.

The problem is how do I in code know where each row starts and ends? Because the data is coming back like this in a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

split the string on line breaks and commas....

```
string input = "YOURINPUTSTRING";
foreach(string line in input.Split('\n'))
{
    //each row
    string[] values in line.Split(',');//add this value array as a new gridview row
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean actually parsing the data so that you have some sort of collection (List or an Array) - you could simply do the following:

```
string yourString = "dog,cat, ... , chips,milk";
string[] items = yourString.Split(',');
```

This would put each of the individual items into an array - which you could iterate through to generate your Grid View.

If you wanted to separate each of the lines (using the new-line character as a delimiter, then you could just use :

```
string yourString = "dog,cat, ... , chips,milk";
string[] lines = yourString.Split('\n'); //Splits each of your lines
//Split the individual string array here using .Split(',')
```

Comment: Yes but how that will take the first "row" of info but how am I gonna know where "grass" starts? There is no comma seperating the 2

Answer (score 1):

I would add:

```
string[] lines = theInputString.Split(new char[]{'\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

And the bind to the datagrid

grid.DataSource=lines;
grid.DataBind();

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you could possibly know, unless you can modify the returned string to include some sort of delimiter (i.e. a semicolon)... it kinda looks in your example that maybe the newline character is the delimiter?

```
dog,cat,snake,bird,cow,parrot,lion;grass,green,fruit,bag,car,melon,coat;apple,orange,grape,butter,jelly,chips,milk
```

If you have a newline in there you could do something like:

```
string[] lines = yourtext.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```